# Choosing a right career pathway?

Tags: research-process, software, changing-fields, international

I am in a very confused situation as to how to decide my career pathway. First of all, a brief intro of myself.

**My Background**
I have completed my BEng in Software Engineering with an ordinary degree. Apart from my Bachelors degree, I do not have any other educational qualifications. Though I have a degree in software engineering, I do not find it interesting to work as a software developer, neither Back-end nor Front-end. I was working for a Software development company but resigned within 1 month.

Now I have decided to change my track completely drifting away from Software Engineering. I have thought of starting a Psychology degree and proceed with it. Meanwhile, am following an on line course in edX, Animal Behavior, since it is from one of my passion. I like to be with environment, nature and studying the behaviors of every animal. I also have a deep interest in documenting and researching about lifestyle of people from various culture and religious backgrounds.

Since my family doesn't know any of these, they think that I am just working as a software engineer and should continue it. I haven't told them about my resignation as well.

I love reading books, doing researches (I tried searching for research projects which I could be a part of it), reading and watching documentaries on various subjects, observing animals and going hiking and trekking to involve with the nature and sometimes cooking. I want to be an entrepreneur, which I have started my business very recently to generate my income for these fun activities.

I need some advices and recommendations from people around me, or people who share my common interests and those think alike. It would be a great help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody can decide your future but yourself. Also, it is unclear what you are asking, or how that relates to academia.

Comment: Do you have access to career counseling through the college you attended? Or can you hire a separate career counselor? We can't identify your strengths and recommend courses of action that help your interests. A professional could also dig into your specific experience at that company and suggest how to keep an eye out for similar environments at future employers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really about Academia, it is more of "figuring out what to do with your professional life".

Academia can certainly help you in the following ways:

- you might take several courses from different areas like Psychology, Animal Behaviour, and many others to find what you are leaning towards.
- those things might inspire you to get a certain graduate degree. However, going into a graduate school is a big decision, and will require time/money investments, so have to be chosen wisely and not instantaneously.
- it can try to accommodate interdisciplinarily (software engineering + *something else*) research if you decide on going to a grad school.

But you certainly have to take the following things into consideration:

- not every hobby can/should be a profession. While it is awesome to do what you love and follow your passion, you have to really understand how different are the professional and amateur ways. That can be achieved by getting experience in those areas, both from the academic and professional directions.
- advice/support from your family and friends will be important. Though they might not immediately support you in your immediate decisions (which depends on their personalities), you will need their opinions and wisdom.
- you seem to have a very scattered vision of yourself, combining psychology, animal behavior, entrepreneurship, software engineering, etc. You might want to explore those things one-by-one but in a quality way.
- getting rid of software engineering completely doesn't sound very good. You may want to incorporate your knowledge in this area to some other (like psychology) and take advantage of interdisciplinary research.
- changing career path comes at a cost of suffering from the shortage of money. You will need to think of backup options to support yourself, especially if your family is not totally aware of your plans.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It really helped me to think further about what I should be doing.